# an efficient algorithm to handle saving unique words to a file

Tags: php, file, unique

What I currently do is, Parse texts from a URL, and then clean the texts and explode them by spaces and save to a file.

What I find hard is,

Saving only unique files incase of scraping multiple urls:

case : scraped words from site.com/page1 and saved unique words to file. When scraping site.com/page2, I need to check if each word is in the file already and save it only if its not present.

What I have in my mind is, take $word[0], and fgets each line from the file and check and save if its not found. But that would be like thousands - hundred thousand times of iterations.

I am not looking for any codes, but just an idea how to handle it efficiently and fast.

Comment: how do you store your words before writing in a file? Array?

Comment: How much data are you roughly dealing with? How many words per page, how many pages?

Comment: @NiftyDude - Yep. Array. I can use unique array to write only the unique words to the file, But next time I scrape, There would be words in the array that is already in the file.

Comment: @thejh - It would be like 10k words per url, and I will be going to the next page after writing the words to the file because there will be a lot of urls to work on.

Comment: Added an answer, see if that fits, if you need more info let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have already stored unique words you got from site1 in a file called `site1.txt`, and you've already scraped words from site2 in an array called `$site2`, now you'd like to store `$site2` line by line in a file `site2.txt`, only storing unique words:

```
$wordsInFile1 = file('site1.txt');
$wordsInFile1 = array_flip($wordsInFile1);

foreach($site2 as $i => $word) {
    if(isset($wordsInFile1[$word])) {
       unset($site2[$i]);
    }
}

// now $site2 contains unique words from site2 and words that are not in site1.txt
```

Comment: That assumes that everything fits into RAM.

Comment: @thejh true that... Hmm, will edit my answer (or delete if I can't find any satisfactory work around)

Comment: @thejh It does - but I would wager that the entire possible data set *will* fit in RAM easily, if it's just standard sets of words.

Comment: Just got an understanding of how this works. 

Ram usage/processing would be nominal? This is meant to work on a shared hosting by the way.

I like your algorithm. Gets the thing done. Just concerned about the resource usages.

Comment: @Kishor you can try first for 2 urls and see how it goes :), I can't really give you an answer without having access to the server

Comment: @MattJ - They are standard words, but the file can be infinitely large :(

Comment: Just one more question. What part of the code do you think would be the resource hog? Importing file? Or checking if the variable is set? 

That would help me because I can change the way rest of the script works and make it go just fine.

Comment: Bottleneck would be I/O, when you are doing `file('file1.txt)`, but I still think it'd be the same with if you do `fgets` each line. Checking set variable would be very negligible :)

Comment: The standard American English word list on my system has 98569 words in it - and is about 912KB in size, so less than 1MB. The Oxford English Dictionary has ~600,000 entries in total - which would still total less than 6MB. There will be some additional overhead in your data structures, but nothing significant if you do it right. This is not "infinitely large" - meaning you can easily afford to do things the simpler way :)

Comment: @MattJ - With infinitely large, I meant the number of lines lol. The default file is already 700k, which is like 15mb+ Basically because it is words, and phrases too. No worries, I got your point.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, your current algorithm is in the complexity class `O(n^2)`. You're iterating over the list again for each word, that's not so good, right. I'd suggest that you first write all the words into the files and then use an efficient algorithm to sort the list. When you've done that, you can remove duplicates. For example, under linux, you can use this command for that:

```
sort -u unsortedList > sortedAndCleanedList
```

Comment: Am sorry, but I missed to include PHP in the tags. looking to handle it with php as this is going to work from the server side fully

Answer (score 1):

`grep <word> file` should work quite fast

Alternatively, you could create an empty file named as md5 of a word, and then check if the md5(word) file exists before adding the word to the main file. Be careful that some filesystems don't allow more than 32767 files in a directory (so you may need to create subdirectories based on the first few chars of the md5 hash)

Comment: Am sorry, but I missed to include PHP in the tags. looking to handle it with php as this is going to work from the server side fully

Comment: if you have your own server, you can run linux/unix commands from PHP

Comment: well, that sounds good, but still, I would like to handle it completely with PHP. Its mainly a learning project to improve myself in PHP, so you know! :) Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: ok, then create empty file for each word, name it md5($word) - using md5 just avoid dealing with different charsets - then check with `file_exists`

Comment: That would be like 1000k+ of files.. I dont think that is viable option :(

Comment: Really this solution is similar to @hakre's, except you're using MD5 and writing the hashes to disk, and hakre is using a hash-table in memory. The idea is the same but hakre's implementation is better.

Comment: I still think `grep` is the way to go - anyways you're gonna ran out of memory long before you run out of disk space (esp with empty files)

Answer (score 1):

You handle it efficiently and fast with a in-memory representation that allows a fast search, like a hashtable.

Let's say you've got a function that returns all words from a file, normalized, not punctation, no whitespace:

```
$words = extract_words('Hello my dear!');
```

where-as `$words` results in:

```
array(
    'hello' => 1,
    'my'    => 1,
    'dear'  => 1,
);
```

You can store this hashtable quickly into a file using [`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export):

```
$file = 'words1.txt';
file_put_contents(sprintf('return %s;', var_export($words, TRUE)));
```

And read it back in using [`include`](http://php.net/include):

```
$words = include($file);
```

To check whether or not that hashmap contains the word, use `isset`:

```
$exist = isset($words[$word]);
```

As you have arrays here, you can merge them across files, diff them etc. - PHP has many array based functions available. I think that's pretty fast if you want to do it with PHP.

If you have larger lists, I suggest you take tools that are used for wordlists of several gigabytes which are normally [written in C](http://hashcat.net/forum/thread-323.html).

Comment: Sounds good, But unfortunately, another reply I got here seems to be better.

btw, extract_words was new to me. Thanks for that :)

Comment: And it gets a bit complicated for me when looping and writing outputs at the end.

I would try a run with your method.!

Comment: @Kishor: `extract_words` needs to be implemented - it does not yet exist (but it should be rather trivial as you write in your question you have the code already, otherwise take a look at [`str_word_count`](http://php.net/str_word_count) and other string functions).

Comment: Ah, thought it was a builtin function. I currently gets the text, explode them by spaces, and array_unique it. :)

Comment: Try: `$words = array_flip(preg_split('/\W+/u', $text, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));` if the original text is UTF-8 encoded, w/o the `u` modifier if not.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your file and then search for the word.

Idea is to keep your file sorted and then use any search algorithm to look for an existing entry in your file with the same pattern. If you cannot find an existing entry, insert new entry.

The cost is keeping the file sorted requires harddisk operations.

Comment: Sure. Since you didn't ask for code, I gave you the idea. I'm editing to give more details.